# Google Maps not loading in Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, html-framework-7

I have a problem with Google Maps not showing when I click the "About" tab:

http://paybulls.com/dist/

```
 <div id="map" style="height:400px; width:400px;"></div>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&    amp;sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Google map example: https://jsfiddle.net/ps74h8sr/1/  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: dear i have copy map from there but my problem is that when i try to use it on framework7 its not working go through link mentioned

Comment: I cannot see any effort from your code. There's no problem integrating google maps with framework 7.  updated https://jsfiddle.net/ps74h8sr/2/

Comment: initMap function is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem a few months ago when using `framework7` and could not fix it.

I instead used this https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/ which is basically google maps wrapped up into a easier to use library.

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event listener i.e.:

```
myApp.onPageInit('map', function(page) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() { 
        [google maps js]
    }
}
```